# Average post age in days per taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I'm building some stats for a directory website and I got stuck calculating the average age of listings assigned to a particular listing type.

I figured out calculating listing age in days by ID:

```
$today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
$listing_date = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d', $id );
$diff = strtotime( $today ) - strtotime( $listing_date );
$age = round( $diff / 86400 );
```

I figured out how to pull listings assigned to a particular listing type by term ID:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'listing-type',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $id
        )
    )
);
$ids = get_posts( $args );
```

This gives me an array of IDs of all listings assigned to a particular listing type.
Now I need to calculate the total age in days for all those listings I retrieved IDs for.

I figured `$cnt = count( $ids );` to get the total number of retrieved listings (IDs), but I can't figure out calculating the total age in days for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a foreach loop :

```
<?php

// Your function to get the diff
function get_diff($id) {
   $today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
   $listing_date = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d', $id );
   $diff = strtotime( $today ) - strtotime( $listing_date );
   $age = round( $diff / 86400 );

   return $age;
}


// We want to store all the diff
$diffs = [];

foreach($ids as $id) {
   $diffs[] = get_diff($id);
}

// Get the average | We filter to remove empty values
$diffs = array_filter($diffs);
if(count($diffs)) {
    echo $average = array_sum($diffs)/count($diffs);
}
```